# Convergence of approximate Gibbs sampling

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, gibbs, approximation, approximate-inference

We have a bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ for which sampling is challenging.

If we were to know how to sample from the conditionals $(X|Y)$ and $(Y|X)$, we could get samples from the joint using [Gibbs sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling) by iterating:
$$x_{t+1} \sim (X|y_t)$$
$$y_{t+1} \sim (Y|x_t).$$

Assume however that we *do not* know how to sample from one of the conditionals (say, $Y|X$), but that, for each $x$, we know how to sample from an approximation $\tilde{Y}_x \approx (Y|X=x)$.

If we assume that $\tilde{Y}_x$ is close to $(Y|X=x)$ in some sense (for example, that the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) between these two distributions is smaller than $\varepsilon$ for all $x$), could we get results about the convergence of the pseudo-Gibbs chain:
$$x_{t+1} \sim (X|Y=y_t)$$
$$y_{t+1} \sim \tilde{Y}_{x_t}?$$

Comment: You'll get convergence, of course, it'll just be to the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ given the approximate distribution of $Y|X$, not the actual distribution.  Given that, the K-L divergence of the converged-to and actual  distributions will be smaller than $\epsilon$ too.

Comment: What do you precisely mean by the joint distribution given the approximate conditional? It is likely that $X|Y$ and $\tilde{Y}_X$ are not the conditionals  of any joint distribution.

Comment: If they are not the conditionals of any joint distribution, then I have no idea of what, if anything, the pseudo-Gibbs sampler will converge to!  Time to upvote the question...

Comment: This comment doesn't answer your question, but you could instead run a M-H to sample from the conditional for $Y|X$. That would be a Metropolis within Gibbs sampler, which would converge to the correct distribution.

Comment: Yes, I guess that $\tilde{Y}_x$ could even be used to design a good proposal for M-H ?
However, I'm mostly interested in high-dimensional settings where MH will have a hard time.

Comment: @PAM Yes, it could be used quite well as a proposal I presume. It may be unfair to assume MH will have a hard time in high dimensional situations. Sometimes MH can surprise you. Worth giving a shot if it means asymptotically exact samples.